# Should I use the repository pattern or mocking framework for 'mocking' a model locally before creating the database tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking

I have an ASP.NET MVC application using Entity Framework Code First.

I want to be able to test my applications 'look-and-feel' and interaction without first creating the database tables. This is by preference as I don't want to have to keep updating the database if I make changes to the model for some reason.

Is this a good place to use the Repository pattern?

My current code:

Model:

```
public class FATTemplateHeader
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AnatomyModelId { get; set; }
    public virtual AnatomyModel AnatomyModel { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [StringLength(16)]
    public string TemplateVersion { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public char Status { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
    public virtual AspNetUser User { get; set; }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IFatTemplateRepository
{
    #region FatTemplateHeader

    IEnumerable<FATTemplateHeader> GetFatTemplateHeaders();
    IEnumerable<FATTemplateHeader> GetFatTemplateHeadersByModel(int modelId);
    FATTemplateHeader GetFatTemplateHeaderByName(string name);

    void InsertFatTemplateHeader(FATTemplateHeader header);
    void DeleteFatTemplateHeader(int headerId);
    void UpdateFatTemplateHeader(FATTemplateHeader header);

    #endregion

    void Save();
}
```

Real class that would use the database:

```
public class FatTemplateRepository : IFatTemplateRepository, IDisposable
{
    private Db _dbContext;

    public FatTemplateRepository(Db context)
    {
        _dbContext = context;
    }

    #region FAT Template Header

    public IEnumerable<FATTemplateHeader> GetFatTemplateHeaders()
    {
        return _dbContext.FATTemplateHeaders.ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<FATTemplateHeader> GetFatTemplateHeadersByModel(int modelId)
    {
        return _dbContext.FATTemplateHeaders.Where(x => x.AnatomyModelId == modelId).ToList();
    }

    public FATTemplateHeader GetFatTemplateHeaderByName(string name)
    {
        return _dbContext.FATTemplateHeaders.Find(name);
    }

    public void InsertFatTemplateHeader(FATTemplateHeader header)
    {
        _dbContext.FATTemplateHeaders.Add(header);
    }

    public void DeleteFatTemplateHeader(int headerId)
    {
        FATTemplateHeader header = _dbContext.FATTemplateHeaders.Find(headerId);
        _dbContext.FATTemplateHeaders.Remove(header);
    }

    public void UpdateFatTemplateHeader(FATTemplateHeader header)
    {
        _dbContext.Entry(header).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    #endregion

    public void Save()
    {
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    // IDispose
    private bool disposed = false;
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _dbContext.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Mock class that uses Lists as collection:

```
public class MockFatTemplateRepository: IFatTemplateRepository
{
    #region FAT Template Header

    private static IList<FATTemplateHeader> mockFatTemplateHeaders;

    public MockFatTemplateRepository()
    {
        if (!mockFatTemplateHeaders.Any())
        {
            // Seed with data
            IList<FATTemplateHeader> mockFatTemplateHeaders = new List<FATTemplateHeader>
            {
                new FATTemplateHeader
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    AnatomyModelId = 1,
                    Description = "TEST 1",
                    TemplateVersion = "1.0",
                    DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                    Status = 'A',
                    CreatedBy = "user1"
                },
                new FATTemplateHeader
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    AnatomyModelId = 1,
                    Description = "TEST 2",
                    TemplateVersion = "1.1",
                    DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                    Status = 'A',
                    CreatedBy = "user1"
                }
            };
        } 
    }


    public IEnumerable<FATTemplateHeader> GetFatTemplateHeaders()
    {
        return mockFatTemplateHeaders;
    }

    public IEnumerable<FATTemplateHeader> GetFatTemplateHeadersByModel(int modelId)
    {
        return mockFatTemplateHeaders.Where(x => x.AnatomyModelId == modelId).ToList();
    }

    public FATTemplateHeader GetFatTemplateHeaderByName(string name)
    {
        return mockFatTemplateHeaders.Where(x => x.Description == name).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public void InsertFatTemplateHeader(FATTemplateHeader header)
    {
        mockFatTemplateHeaders.Add(header);
    }

    public void DeleteFatTemplateHeader(int headerId)
    {
        FATTemplateHeader deleteHeader = mockFatTemplateHeaders.Where(x => x.Id == headerId).FirstOrDefault();

        if (deleteHeader != null)
            mockFatTemplateHeaders.Remove(deleteHeader);
    }

    public void UpdateFatTemplateHeader(FATTemplateHeader header)
    {
        FATTemplateHeader updateHeader = mockFatTemplateHeaders.Where(x => x.Id == header.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (updateHeader != null)
        {
            updateHeader = header;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public void Save()
    {
    }

}
```

Also I have read a bit about using a mocking framework such as Moq, but it seems that it is mostly used for Unit Testing.

I am totally confused as to whether I should using the interface as I have in my code above or if this is the job for a mocking framework.

Lastly I am confused about how to inject my model into my controller so that when I am satisfied with my Model and I do create my database tables, that the switch over from Mock class to real class is simple.

Thanks,

Neill

Comment: I agree that Moq is mostly used for unit testing and would not be super useful for testing you UI. I think what I would do is use dependency injection and using an interface for you UI layer then register you test service using DI when testing it and then when ready inject the dbContext but this can be done with just a simple interface vs repo pattern.

Comment: Thanks Derek. what do you mean by "using an interface for you UI layer then register you test service"? Currently In my controller I instantiate an object of IFatTemplateRepository called fatTemplateRepository and have 2 constructors. In the first I set fatTemplateRepository to either type MockFatTemplateRepository for testing or call the second constructor which takes my database context as parameter. In that second constructor I set this.fatTemplateRepository = fatTemplateRepository.